# Getting the device internal storage(not app directory) and external storage (SD CARD) , is this the right way?

Tags: android, android-storage

I went through plenty of articles( I mean too many to list out here) to find out the best way to find the root folder of the device storage and the sd card.
The one that worked for finding the sd card path was from [this](https://gist.github.com/PauloLuan/4bcecc086095bce28e22#gistcomment-2591001) gist, finding the root internal storage path was still difficult.

**I do not want to use the storage access framework as of now** and I am targeting android 10 with the  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` flag.

Finally, I found a way to make it work and  it seems very easy, almost too good to be true. So I want to verify if it is ok to go ahead with this code without falling into unforeseen pitfalls in the future.

Here I am getting the root folder of my device (Samsung A50s - SM-A507fN/DS 128GB)
both internal and external SD card

```
 private fun getStoragePaths() {
    val mediaStorageDir = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDirs(null)
    mediaStorageDir.forEach {
        val path = it.absolutePath.toString()
        log("complete path $path")
        val rootPath = path.substring(0,path.indexOf("Android"))
        log("root path $rootPath")
    }
}
```

my logs

```
2021-04-21 11:59:00.501 4037-4037/com.pt.workingwithstorage I/myStorage: complete path /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pt.workingwithstorage/files
2021-04-21 11:59:00.501 4037-4037/com.pt.workingwithstorage I/myStorage: root path /storage/emulated/0/
2021-04-21 11:59:00.501 4037-4037/com.pt.workingwithstorage I/myStorage: complete path /storage/0C5B-9496/Android/data/com.pt.workingwithstorage/files
2021-04-21 11:59:00.501 4037-4037/com.pt.workingwithstorage I/myStorage: root path /storage/0C5B-9496/
```

When I used the complete path `/storage/emulated....../files`
Neither the file or the folder was created.
But using the root path that I substringed worked perfectly.
Can I go on with this without any problems in the future?.

Comment: Yes, getExternalFilesDirs() is the way to go and you can create folders and files there without any permission. Sadly you code is overly complicated and i cannor see what you try exactly.

Comment: so getting the internal and external storage root path will work regardless of the devices up to android 10. ?
If it's unreadable ignore everything after `if(arrayList.isEmpty()).....`
I am just reading the root strings to make the files and folders after that line

Comment: Please post code without that arraylist to begin with.

Comment: sorry I just did

Comment: ??? You are adding all kinds of stuff to an array list and you are not creating directories...

Comment: I know, I was trying to clean the code, sorry to leave in the unnecessary part so is this the way to go across all devices?

Comment: That is what i often use yes. But sadly an usb otg stick will not be in it using modern devices.

Comment: ok thank you @blackapps. Now I am trying to query the available and free size in both the storages. Could you tell me how or could you share some links.

Comment: That is a complete new problem. You better make a new post to ask.

Comment: sure. I will try it for some time and ask if I can't figure it out. Thanks again